# Problems with obtaining modified date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have an opened workbook called "Visor Portafolio.xls" and I want to write its last modified date on my current workbook (the one running the macro) into cell H6. I want to put this at the end of a macro that I use.

I've tried a lot of different solutions but it won't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("H6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = LastSaveDate()    
End Sub


Function LastSaveDate()
     Application.Volatile True
     LastSaveDate = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
 End Function
```

base on: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/insert-the-date-an-excel-workbook-was-last/c0c7335e-fc0d-43c7-b32d-215f84b452cc